# Error copying from Excel 2003: "The information cannot be pasted..."

Tags: excel, excel-2003

Because of the 65,536 row limit, I need to merge the values of several worksheets in a pre-2007 workbook, by copying and pasting into a post-2007 workbook which does not have the limit.

This code worked for the first worksheet, but the second worksheet:

```
destRow = 65537
Set destRange = destSheet.Cells(destRow, 1)
Set srcRange = srcSheet.Range("A1:R65536")
srcRange.Copy destRange
```

results in the following error:

> "The information cannot be pasted because the Copy area and the paste area are not the same size."

I get this error whether I do the operation manually, or with VBA.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in Excel post-2007, when copying a whole Excel 2003 sheet and pasting it into a post-2007 Excel location that's not A1.

**The workaround:**

If I split the copy/paste operation into two chunks, it works without error:

```
destRow = 65537
' Chunk 1
Set destRange = destSheet.Cells(destRow, 1)
Set srcRange = srcSheet.Range("A1:R65535")
srcRange.Copy destRange

' Chunk 2
Set destRange = destSheet.Cells(destRow + 65535, 1)
Set srcRange = srcSheet.Range("A65536:R65536")
srcRange.Copy destRange
```